# Find recurring purchasing in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate

I would like to filter my data for recurring purchases. My data looks like this:

```
User Material Date
1    10001    20150119
1    10002    20150120
2    10003    20160121
2    10002    20181212
3    10004    20181110
1    10001    20150419
2    10003    20160421
2    10002    20180912
2    10002    20180612
```

and so on....

Now I want to filter the data by user material and who buys which product more often, for example every 3 months (quarter) per year.

My desired output, for example, would look like this:

```
User Material RecurringPurchasing
1    10001    2
2    10003    2
2    10002    3
```

Because of the output I am flexible. That was just an idea of mine. Unfortunately, I don't know how I can portray something like that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I get the frequency with: library(plyr)
counts <- ddply(df, .(df$user, df$Material), nrow)
names(counts) <- c("User", "Material", "Freq") but I don't know how to use the date.

Comment: What do you mean by recurring purchases? Do you want to know for each material which user bought the maximum ? Something like `df %>%
  count(Material, User) %>%
  group_by(Material) %>%
  slice(which.max(n))`

Comment: I would like to know which user buys which material recurrently. For example, if a user buys a material every quarter of the year, he will get factor 4. if he only bought in two quarters, 2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) # part of tidyverse but calling it out because of the quarter function

df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
User Material Date
1    10001    20150119
1    10002    20150120
2    10003    20160121
2    10002    20181212
3    10004    20181110
1    10001    20150419
2    10003    20160421
2    10002    20180912
2    10002    20180612")

df %>%
 mutate(quarter = quarter(Date)) %>%
 count(User, Material, quarter) %>%
 group_by(User, Material) %>%
 summarize(RecurringPurchasing = sum(n)) %>%
 filter(RecurringPurchasing > 1)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   User [2]
   User Material RecurringPurchasing
  <int>    <int>               <int>
1     1    10001                   2
2     2    10002                   3
3     2    10003                   2
```

Comment: This is perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Ben G